# Tensorflow Serving can't find model

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

**Can't get this dockerfile to work. I keep getting the same error:**

*tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:365] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: Could not find base path /models/model for servable model with error Not found: /models/model not found*

**When running docker run by itself locally it works fine, and the image builds without error. But when I run the image, it can't find the model.**

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl -fsSLO https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz \
  && tar xzvf docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz \
  && mv docker/docker /usr/local/bin \
  && rm -r docker docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz


RUN docker run -p 8501:8501 \
    --mount type=bind,source=/home/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/tmp/monitored/upgrade_rate_predictions,target=/models/upgrade_rate_predictions \
    -e MODEL_NAME=upgrade_rate_predictions \
    -t tensorflow/serving &
```

Comment: Hello, is there a reason to run docker inside docker? Why do you need this? Running the docker run command from your host is not enough?

Comment: For scaleability we're planning to run within our K8 cluster.

Comment: Ok, but even in a K8s cluster you can run the base image `tensorflow/serving:latest` without the need to install docker in it. You can just mount your model file as a volume. Here, you probably don't want to build your model at `docker build` time (having a `RUN docker run ...` command in your Dockerfile is what it does). Anyway, your current Dockerfile won't work because your model (`/home/serving/tensorflow_serving/...upgrade_rate_predictions`) does not exist during the build of your Dockerfile.

Comment: Makes sense. I removed those pieces and just left the `FROM` and the `RUN docker run` piece. However, could you please elaborate a bit on what you mean by model does not exist during the build of docker? I'm new to all this, so forgive me if it's a dumb question.

Comment: Just keeping the `FROM`and `RUN docker run` won't work neither, because when running `docker build`, it will say that `docker` is not installed. My point is that you probably don't need to install and run `docker` commands inside your `Dockerfile`. If your goal is to run your model serving in a k8s cluster, there is no need to define a custom image, `tensorflow/serving` is fine by itself.

Comment: Regarding the "model not found" error, there is no `/home/serving/.../upgrade_rate_predictions` in the `tensorflow/serving` image. If you want the model to be available during the `docker build`, you'll have to `COPY upgrade_rate_predictions /home/serving/.../upgrade_rate_predictions` before running your `docker run` command. But again, running a `docker run` command in your `Dockerfile` is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Moreover, the `docker run` command in your `Dockerfile` won't run the model serving as you would expect. It will not expose the port 8501 to your host, and anyway it will terminate quickly because you're running it in background (`&`).

Comment: Take a look at the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker. There is no need to have a custom `Dockerfile` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. Was able to build from the documentation for kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to follow the kubernetes documentation and get this to work. Had to build the image up step-by-step and copy files into the container. Problem was trying to use `docker build` and paths not being recognized. Thanks @norbjd, you were a lot of help!.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_kubernetes

[Instructions from Tensorflow Serving documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdCGB.png)